# "TANTO o más importante" vs "TAN o más importante"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos

Estaba haciendo ejercicios para el examen DELE C1 y había una pregunta de hueco:

> Pues bien, resulta que contemplar el mundo en tres dimensiones espaciales resulta que es `______` o más importante.

Hay alternativas de "tan", "mucho" y "tanto". Yo elegí "tan" pero la respuesta correcta sale "tanto". Por qué? Pensaba que "tan" se usa para adjetivos y "tanto" se usa para sustantivos?

Comment: como que falta contexto en la oración de ejemplo, por lo menos con lo que se compara; por lo otro tan/tanto se usa indistintamente de forma general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabra *tanto* se apocopa en *tan* exclusivamente cuando va seguida inmediatamente por un adjetivo, sin importar lo que venga después en la frase. No es el caso del ejemplo, ya que se interpone la construcción *o más*; por consiguiente, la respuesta correcta es *tanto*. Obsérvese la diferencia entre estas dos formas de construir la misma frase:

> Pues bien, resulta que contemplar el mundo en tres dimensiones
>   espaciales es *tanto* o más importante.
>
> Pues bien, resulta que contemplar el mundo en tres dimensiones
>   espaciales es *tan* importante o más.

(He quitado el segundo *resulta que* porque me ha parecido evidente que uno de los dos sobra; podríamos haber quitado el primero y dejado el segundo sin cambiar el sentido de la frase).

Ocurre algo parecido en otros casos de apócopes. Por ejemplo, *mucho* se apocopa a *muy* en condiciones similares a las de *tanto* y *tan*:

> Este coche es *muy* grande.
>
> Este coche es *mucho* más grande.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el uso de `tanto` en tu pregunta dada sería corecto.  Típicamente, se usa `tan`/`tanto` en el caso de comparación.

`tan[to] importante como`

`tan[to] [pon adjectivo aquí] como`

`tan[to] importante que`

Todos estos ejemplos indica una comparación completa.  Pero tu pregunta dada no trata de comparación.  `Tanto o más importante`.  Falta la otra parte de comparación... el uso de `que` o `como`...

Pero este uso precede un operativo `o` y `más`
Este uso de `tanto` indica una cantidad intangible.  Una cantidad de importancia.

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=662183